# How to add title to header without breaking search box

Tags: magento2, static-block, header, magento2.2, styles

I am creating a theme for magento 2.2. Created my first custom block in app/frontend/CUSTOM VENDOR/CUSTOM THEME/Magento_Theme/templates/heading.phtml containing the following code:

```
<?php
//create block_identifier static block
echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('block_identifier')->toHtml();?>

<?php echo __('<div class="block heading_title"><h1>Murky<br>Apparel</h1></div>');
?>
```

I have also successfully loaded the new block within app/frontend/CUSTOM VENDOR/CUSTOM THEME/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml using this code:

```
<!-- Add custom title block to header -->
<referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="customblock" before="top.search" template="Magento_Theme::heading.phtml" />
</referenceContainer>
```

The block is displaying on the front-end, but it pushes down the search bar and floats to the left, leaving no space between it and the logo. Here is an example image:

[image: broken header text]

I would like to know the following:

1) How do I implement a clearfix so that the search bar displays where it is supposed to, to the left of the cart button?

2) How do I add either padding or margin to the  tag or its parent div?

Desired outcome would be something like this:

[image: desired header]

I am a newcomer to magento, so a clear explanation of how to implement custom styles might be helpful. TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though Joshua is not wrong its a bad practice to add your own .css files.

For extending the theme css classes or overwriting them use `/web/css/source/_theme.less`. For adding css to your own custom classes (logo is already used by magento) use `/web/css/source/_extend.less`.

Even more so these filles are autogenerated by magento and you don't need to add them to any xml.

For a better understanding about how to use Magento's Block system (and a .`phtml file` is not a `Block` but a `Template` that is used within a `Block`) i highly recommend the following URL :

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html

But i'm guessing that you don't see how you can easily create your own template files from the one from **magento 2**

You can inherit any theme that Magento defines by adding the following to your **theme.xml**

```
<parent>magento/blank</parent>
```

Then you can just copy any .phtml file in the corresponding directory within your theme and it will be overwritten.

In your example you want to edit the logo box of Magento 2. You can add Logo's within magento from your theme settings (`content->design->configuration->theme edit -> HTML Head`)

The logo is defined within `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/header/logo.phtml`

We can copy that file to our `app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_theme/templates/html/header/logo.phtml` and then just adjust it to our needs. It will automatically overwrite the .pthml file of Magento and you don't need to adjust any xml's.

As you noticed we need to follow the exact folder directory that Magento uses. We do not need to define its within the view/frontend folder because we are in the `app/design/frontend` folder already,  `magento/module_theme` becomes `Magento_theme` and from there you just follow the directory that Magento wants.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation of the file structure! I had to rebuild the whole website at one point because I incorrectly copied files from vendor/magento and couldn't work it out.

Although, in this instance, I don't actually need to alter the logo phtml file. I would simply need to add a margin to the logo or a custom class attached to it.

I will now attempt this using the _extend.less method and a custom class added to the logo.

One question, though, how would you recommend attaching a custom class to the existing logo?

Comment: I gave you a +1 for this already, but I don't have enough reputation for it to display.

Comment: Ah I see... I need to copy the logo.phtml file in order to add the custom class.. correct?

Comment: You can copy the logo.phtml and add your own class to the div that you want and use that in your _extend.less or you can use the #logo in your _theme.less and use that id to give it some padding

Comment: Yes I got it sorted following your instructions. Had to do a tiny bit of research on the magento framework but I think that was due to my understanding being limited rather than your explanation. Thanks again!

Comment: I try to give the resources to help you understand the framework but its impossible to explain everything in 1 post. I'm glad you did some of the research yourself. Thanks!

Comment: No worries I think I just haven't gotten to grips with it properly enough to understand your explanation, not that it was lacking.

Comment: An upvote on my comment would help me also gaining some points. I'm trying to get top grower this month :D

Comment: Sorry I don't think I can give upvotes yet. Only joined the magento stack recently. If I get my reputation up enough then I'll make sure I give you a vote!

Already upvoted on the answer but haven't got enough reputation for it to display.

Comment: Ah no problem :D

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the question, the first problem, causing the search box to display incorrectly, was solved by editing the `before` attribute in the default.xml file:

```
<referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
  <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="customblock" before="page-header.end" template="Magento_Theme::heading.phtml" />
</referenceContainer>
```

The h1 container extends to the width of its parent. So, in order to create a space between it and the logo, I had to declare a `<head>` inside default.xml and reference a custom stylesheet:

```
<head>
  <css src="css/style.css" media="all" />
</head>
<body>
...
```

Inside the new stylesheet, located at app/frontend/CUSTOM VENDOR/CUSTOM THEME/web/css/style.css, I added the following code:

```
.logo {
  padding-right: 1rem;
}
```